# Batch file not executing psftp commands

Tags: t-sql, batch-file, sftp, putty, psftp

I am trying to upload a file from my local system to an FTP which is configured in Linux machine using T-SQL cmd. I have created a batch file with the commands to be executed which is working correctly in `cmd` where it is not working in T-SQL while calling the same batch file in SQL using xp_CMDShell. Please find below the commands I have used.

Batch file cmd:

```
cd C:\Program Files\PuTTY
psftp.exe
open FTPip
username
password
put D:\localpath\filename /home/destinationpath/filename
quit
```

T-SQL:

```
EXEC master..xp_CMDShell 'D:\batchfilepath\batchfile.bat'
```

T-SQL response:

> C:\Windows\system32>cd C:\Program Files\PuTTY  NULL C:\Program
>   Files\PuTTY>psftp.exe psftp: no hostname specified; use "open
>   host.name" to connect psftp> quit NULL C:\Program Files\PuTTY>open
>   ftpip  'open' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NULL C:\Program Files\PuTTY>username
>   'username' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NULL C:\Program Files\PuTTY>password
>   'password' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file. NULL C:\Program Files\PuTTY>quit
>   'quit' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable
>   program or batch file. NULL

Please let me know where I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

Your are combining `psftp` commands and Windows commands into one file. That cannot work. The batch file stops on the call to the `psftp` and waits for it to finish. `psftp` on the contrary does not know that the batch file even exist, so it cannot read its commands from there.

Put your `psftp` commands (lines `open` though `quit`) into a separate file (`upload.txt`) and execute it with the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\psftp.exe -b c:\path\to\upload.txt
```

(you can execute that command directly from T-SQL or put it to your batch file)

---

*Note your batch file cannot work from `cmd` either, contrary to what you claim in your question. You have probably meant, that typing those lines in `cmd` manually works, what is something else.*